# Pass data from Sunday to week before in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My aggregation gets the data of documents per week. In this case I'm getting data from days 18 to 24 of may:

```
{ "_id" : 20, "count" : 795 }
{ "_id" : 21, "count" : 221 }
```

Since 'week' in mongo starts from sundays, the data from sundays is creating a new week (In this case is 21). Is there any way I can transfer the data from Sundays to the week before or backwards?

The result would be:

```
{ "_id" : 20, "count" : 1016 }
```

Aggregation:

```
[{
    $match: {
       start_date: {
          $gte: ISODate('2020-05-18T00:00:01'),
          $lte: ISODate('2020-05-24T23:59:59')
       }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
       week: {
          $week: '$start_date'
       },
       solved: '$solved',
       survey: '$survey'
    }
}, {
    $group: {
       _id: '$week',
       count: {
          $sum: 1
       }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
       _id: 1
    }
}]
```

UPDATE:
[image: Mongo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below query will do the trick.

The `timezone` key in `if` condition can be removed if your `week-wise-sort` is independent of the time zone of `ISODate` value in DB

```
db.<Collection-Name>.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
           start_date: {
              $gte: ISODate('2020-05-18T00:00:01'),
              $lte: ISODate('2020-05-24T23:59:59')
           }
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
           week: {
               "$cond": {
                   "if": {"$eq": [{"$dayOfWeek": {"date": "$start_date", "timezone": "-0500"}}, 1]},
                   "then": {"$subtract": [{"$week": '$start_date'}, 1]},
                   "else": {"$week": '$start_date'}
               }
           },
           solved: '$solved',
           survey: '$survey'
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
           _id: '$week',
           count: {
              $sum: 1
           }
        }
    }, {
        $sort: {
           _id: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I am very sorry, I entered `$week` instead of `$dayOfWeek`. The updated code should work.

Comment: Thank you, there was an improvement but there is still a lot of data in week 21 :/

Comment: Since I'm in Mexico the timezone difference is 5 hours, so I'm getting data from the 25th until 05:00:00. I put the image in the question. Do you know how to pass data from 05:00 am from that day to the day before?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the `timezone` parameter whose value should be the difference in the timezone from UTC time in `string`. Since you have mentioned that the your timezone is at a -5 hour difference, I have added even that in the updated answer. I hope this helps.